# Make SwiftUI TabView wrap its content

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

Is it possible to make paged `TabView` that wraps its content? I don't know the height of the content (it is an Image resized to fit the width of the screen) so I can't use `frame` modifier.

My code looks like this:

```swift
ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
    TabView {
        ForEach(data) { entry in
            VStack {
                entry.image
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                Text(entry.description)
            }
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))

    Color.red
        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
}
```

The problem is that the `TabView` is as big as the screen and `PageIndicator` is placed in the top right corner of the screen instead of top right corner of the image. Tanks for any suggestions.

**EDIT:**

I've added code that is reproducible. PageIndicator was replaced by red rectangle.

```swift
struct Test: View {
    struct Entry: Identifiable {
        let image: Image
        let description: String

        var id: String { description }
    }

    let data = [
        Entry(image: Image(systemName: "scribble"), description: "image 1"),
        Entry(image: Image(systemName: "trash"), description: "image 2")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(data) { entry in
                    VStack {
                        entry.image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)

                        Text(entry.description)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))

            Color.red
                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `PageIndicator` is not placed on the image, because you didn't place it there. You are placing it in a layer on top of a `VStack` that happens to contain text and an image that can be shorter than the screen. If you want the `PageIndicator` on the image, then you need to do that specifically. You didn't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but does something like this work:

```
TabView {
    ForEach(data) { entry in
        VStack {
            entry.image
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .overlay(
                    PageIndicator()
                )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(
                    PageIndicator()
                )

            Text(entry.description)
        }
    }
}
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

The `.overlay()` needs to go before the `.frame()` so it stays on the image, instead of overlaying the `.frame()`.

Edit:

Based off of the MRE and the comment, here is alternate solution that aligns the `PageIndicator` to the top of the image, but does not scroll with the image. Please note that this is not a perfect MRE as the image heights are different, but this solution actually accounts for that as well. Lastly, I added a yellow background on the image to show that things are aligned properly.

```
struct Test: View {

    struct Entry: Identifiable {
        let image: Image
        let description: String
        
        var id: String { description }
    }
    
    let data = [
        Entry(image: Image(systemName: "scribble"), description: "image 1"),
        Entry(image: Image(systemName: "trash"), description: "image 2")
    ]
    
    @State private var imageTop: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topTrailing) {
            TabView {
                ForEach(data) { entry in
                    VStack {
                        entry.image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                            .background(
                                GeometryReader { imageProxy in
                                    Color.clear.preference(
                                        key: ImageTopInGlobal.self,
                                        // This returns the top of the image relative to the TabView()
                                        value: imageProxy.frame(in: .named("TabView")).minY)
                                }
                            )

                        Text(entry.description)
                    }
                }
            }
            // This gives a reference to another container for comparison
            .coordinateSpace(name: "TabView")
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(height: imageTop)
                Color.red
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
        }
        // You either have to ignore the safe area or account for it with regard to the TabView(). This was simpler.
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .onPreferenceChange(ImageTopInGlobal.self) {
            imageTop = $0
        }
    }
}

private extension Test {
    struct ImageTopInGlobal: PreferenceKey {
        static let defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
        
        static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat,
                           nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
            value = nextValue()
        }
    }
}
```

Final edit:

In response to the last comment, my answer is a qualified no. I don't think there is any way to make a `TabView` hug its contents. (I take the original question using the term wrap to mean hug, as the `TabView` always "wraps" its contents.) If you try to use a preference key, the `TabView` collapses. There would have to be a `minHeight` or `height` set to prevent this which defeats the purpose of the hugging attempt.

Comment: Hi, no this does not work. I need the PageIndicator to be above the TabView, it can't scroll with the content. I will provide reproducible example.

Comment: I've added the example. If you run it, you can see that the red rectangle does not move when user swipes right or left - that's what I need. My problem is that I need to move the rectangle down so that it aligns with the top right corners of the images (images all have the same aspect ratio). And that's the thing I can't achieve.

Comment: Added to the answer.

Comment: Perfect :) I suppose that the answer to my original question - Is it possible to make paged TabView that wraps its content? - is no. Can you add this to your answer so I can accept this?